# Creating a hybrid Vue static site and component library using Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

From what I've been able to gather, with Vite you can either build a Vue application in static site mode or as a component library, but I guess what I'm trying to do is both? I would like to be able to create a static Vue 3 application that I can publish to NPM in addition to treating it like a component library.

I've created a Typescript Vue application using the Vite create template (`npm create vite@latest`). This template generates the scaffolding for a simple Vue application using the composition API along with the following simple Vite config for building the application:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
})
```

Building this, it produces a `dist` directory containing `index.html` and the compiled Vue application:

```
dist/
  assets/
    index-aade8870.js
  index.html (references index-aade8870.js above)
```

If I adjust the config to build the application as a component library using the following config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { resolve } from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
      name: 'my-package',
      fileName: 'my-package',
    }
  }
})
```

It outputs a file, `my-package.js`, containing the exports in the entry point, `src/index.js`:

```
dist/
  my-package.js
  my-package.umd.cjs
```

I can create two separate Vite configs, one for building the Vue application and one for building as a library and that ultimate results in a `dist/` directory containing everything from above:

```
dist/
  assets/
    index-aade8870.js
  my-package.js
  my-package.umd.cjs
  index.html (references index-aade8870.js above)
```

The `my-package.js` can be imported externally, but I'm effectively duplicating parts of the code in the build output. If I try to import classes from the built JS (`index-aade8870.js`), the import fails with an `ambiguous indirect export` error.

Is there a way to configure Vite such that it builds the Vue application while also allowing the exported variables to be imported?